# HIveQL: Is there any way to convert semi colon separated value to multiple columns using SQL as mentioned in image attached

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

[image: Red Shows the input and green depicts the required output.]

Column vasm has values (username and id) for multiple persons separated by a semicolon. The requirement is to separate out username and id as two different columns.Please advise how to do this in HiveQL or SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `split` function to create an array of strings, and then select each array element:

```
with base as (
      select split(vasm, ";") as part
      from   mytable
)
select part[0] as vasm_fullname, part[1] as vasm_username
from base
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of solution to the requirement. If any optimization is possible, then please let me know.

WITH base
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT CASE 
            WHEN c.vasm LIKE '%;%'
                THEN split(c.vasm, ";")
            WHEN c.vasm LIKE '%),%'
                THEN split(c.vasm, ",")
            ELSE split(c.vasm, "^")
            END AS part
    FROM gcs_stage.apjgc_seller_report_renewals c where c.vasm is not NULL
    )
SELECT 
case when part [1] is NULL
THEN
    substr(trim(part [0]),1,instr(trim(part [0]),'(')-1)
ELSE
    concat((substr(trim(part [0]),1,instr(trim(part [0]),'(')-1)), (concat(', ',(substr(trim(part [1]),1,instr(trim(part [1]),'(')-1) ))))
END AS vasm_fullname,
CASE when part[1] is NULL
THEN
    substr(trim(part [0]),instr(trim(part [0]),'(')+1 , (instr(trim(part [0]),')')-instr(trim(part [0]),'('))-1)
ELSE
    concat((substr(trim(part [0]),instr(trim(part [0]),'(')+1 , (instr(trim(part [0]),')')-instr(trim(part [0]),'('))-1)), (concat(', ', (substr(trim(part [1]),instr(trim(part [1]),'(')+1 , (instr(trim(part [1]),')')-instr(trim(part [1]),'('))-1)))))
END AS vasm_username
FROM base;